# Why is a [ being added to my prompt after upgrading to OS X 10.11?

Tags: bash, prompt, osx-elcapitan

Since upgrading from OS X 10.10 to 10.11, my Bash prompt has started to behave strangely. A configuration that I've been using for years without issues and started adding a `[`, on the line *above* the current line. That is, if I have

```
 ~/dir $ cd foo
```

and hit return, I get

```
[~/dir $ cd foo
 ~/dir/foo $
```

or, if I just have

```
 ~/dir $
```

and hit return, I get

```
[~/dir $ 
 ~/dir $
```

I get the same behavior regardless of the command I enter (or if, as above, I enter none).

Even if I completely empty my `.bash_profile` I still get this behavior.

What can I do to fix this (and why might this suddenly have started happening as the result of the upgrade to El Capitan)?

Comment: What does `declare -p PS1` say in a terminal that is having this problem?

Comment: @EtanReisner: `declare -x PS1="\\[\\e[0;32m\\]\\[\\e[0;33m\\]\\w\\[\\e[1;32m\\] \\\$ \\[\\e[m\\]"`

Comment: @anubhava: `3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin15)`

Comment: @anubhava: I still get this with an empty `.bash_profile` (see update to question).

Comment: @anubhava: No. It continues to behave as above.

Comment: El Captian ships with emulator-specific files (e.g., `/etc/bashrc_Apple_Terminal`), which may modify the value of `PROMPT_COMMAND`. I don't see anything in the file that affects the value of `PS1`, though.

Comment: I've edited your title to reflect what is actually happening; I suspect a lot of people may have the same question.

Comment: @chepner: Good thanks.  I'll edit the post too to remove unnecessary details. This is clearly something more general.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not about the bash setting or any other bash config file. You just need to uncheck "Automatically Mark Prompt Lines" option in Edit menu of Terminal app.

Comment: Good catch. I don't use Terminal myself, and haven't had a chance to look into what the marks are or how you would use them yet.

Comment: Wow, indeed: good catch. What's the purpose of that setting (or bookmarks for that matter); and why is it now on by default?

Comment: Looks like a way to scroll back quickly. For instance, you might have run several commands which each had many lines of output; there are keyboard shortcuts for quickly jumping back to a previous mark.

Comment: See here for more details about this feature: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/209635/what-functionality-do-marks-offer-in-the-el-capitan-terminal

Comment: Disabling automatic marking is overkill. You can simply hide the marks if you don't want to see them: **View > Hide/Show Marks**

Answer (score 0):

The new **Marks** feature in El Capitan 10.11 adds structure to the terminal contents by marking prompt lines and other interesting content, enabling operations like navigating, selecting, Copying, Printing and deleting commands or their output.

You can hide the marks if you don't want to see them, with the **View > Hide/Show Marks** menu item.

It should be rare that someone actually needs to turn off automatic marking of prompt lines, since, other than their visual representation—which you can turn off—they are passive and only affect the new Marks-related commands. The **Edit > Marks > Automatically Mark Prompt Lines** menu item—which is a persistent preference—exists primarily in case you want to have complete manual control over which lines are marked, by using the other commands in the **Marks** submenu.

A very good explanation of what you can do with Marks and the related commands is found in [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/209907/6883) to [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/209635/).